# Does numexpr support special bessel functions?

Tags: python, bessel-functions, numexpr

I need to evaluate BesselK function at about ten million points. I know `scipy.special` supports this as `scipy.special.kv(n, x)`, but I want a faster evaluation as well as a memory efficient evaluation. Ideally `numexpr` would be good, and I tried `numexpr.evaluate("kv(n, x)")` as well as `numexpr.evaluate("besselk(n,x)")` but both did not work. Does anyone know the exact command for BesselK in `numexpr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numexpr docs list the supported functions, and, alas, Bessel functions are not in it.

http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/user_guide.html

You can try looking around for alternative implementations, e.g. from GSL or boost, but frankly I doubt the speed difference is going to be non-trivial, if any at all.

What *might* be relevant is avoiding the loops over the points on the python side. Either just use array-valued arguments to `scipy.special.kv` or drop to Cython and use the `cython_special` version with looping in Cython.